# Create a common Object facebook sdk android fitness.runs

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to create a **common object** with this code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("type", "fitness.course");
params.putString("url", "http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614");
param.putString("title", "Sample Course");       
params.putString("description", "");
Request request = new Request(
Session.getActiveSession(),
"me/objects/fitness.course",
params,
HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback(){
@Override
public void onCompleted(Response response) {
if(response.getError()==null)
System.out.println("Object succesfully created!!");
else
System.out.println("Object NOT  Created!!"+response.getError());                            
               }}
             );
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
```

but I read this in my Logcat:

```
  10-07 15:33:04.009: I/System.out(23284): Object NOT created!! {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter.}
```

I dont understand the error message... What do I do to create a Course object and update the data (gps status) of my course? I need of a back end server to store the data of my course? The back-end server is only an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says all, you're supplying `og:type` from both your POST request and your URL.

As of the new FB OpenGraph SDK, you can have ad-hoc URL-less objects. What you're trying to do is use that API while at the same time using the self-hosted version of the API.

I'd suggest either taking the URL parameter out, taking `og:type` out of the URL you have set up, and definitely giving the documentation a second read. Here is the documentation for [self hosted objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/) and here is the article for [app owned objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/).

Comment: Ok I dont have clear if app owned object can contain a GPS track.

Comment: Did you attempt it and see what happens? According to [the fitness.course documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.course) I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: In the Object Browser https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser I try to add a GeoPoint at an Object Course... but it dont work.. tell me a JSON or array is required where I can found correct sintax to put my GeoPoint?

Comment: A `GeoPoint` is a java object. The Facebook API takes JSON input. You need to translate that object into an format the API can understand, which most likely will be an array of [latitude, longitude].

Comment: You'll need to supply more information than that to get help. Edit your question with what you're doing and what the result is.

Comment: I'm editing a Course common Object (fitness.runs) using this tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser I try to edit fitness:metrics field using your sintax but the window shut down and no modification are do at fitness:metrics field. I cant post my screenshot beacause my reputation is too low.